# React Router v4 - passing state with <Link />

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to pass a list of objects which are in the state of a component. I'm trying to pass it with a  element doing something likes this:

```
<Link 
    to={{
        pathname: `/contributors/${contributor.id}`,
        state: {linkState: this.state.contributors}
    }}
>
```

But console shows an error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History':
>   Symbol(react.element) could not be cloned.

What does it mean and what can I do about that?

Comment: Does `this.state.contributors` have a large size? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26291578/2079735

Comment: Yes, it does, it is an array that has about 1k objects

Comment: History state has a size limit see the answer I linked.

Comment: So what can I do if I want to pass the information?

Comment: I would suggest looking at storing it in local state via `redux` rather than history state. I have added answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been answered by @GregBeaver here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26291578/2079735

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history
>
> ...
>
> Looks like the simple answer is that possible the state you are passing in is serializing to **larger than 640k**

I would suggest looking into using `redux` and storing the value into local state rather than history state.