# Why `Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History'` when using `Link` from react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've seen similar posts but couldn't find an answer and in my case, I'm trying to pass an action from `<App />`:

```
  addExpense = (expense) => {
    console.log('Hello From AddExpenseForm');
  }
```

to `/create` route where I'm rendering `<AddExpenseForm />` component

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/create',
  state: { addExpense: this.addExpense }
}}> Create Expense</Link>
```

The link is rendered but when I click on it I get an error in console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function (expense) {
      console.log('Hello From addExpense');
    } could not be cloned
```

Why is that and what's the workaround here?

### My updated code:

Routes in Index.js:

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
          <Route path="/create" exact component={AddExpenseForm}/>
          <Route path="/expense/:expenseId" name="routename" component={ExpenseDetails} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

App.js:

```
  addExpense = (expense = {}) => {
    console.log('Hello From AddExpenseForm');
  }

  goToNextPage = (addExpense) => {
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/create',
      state: { addExpense: this.addExpense }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header
        />
        <button onClick={this.goToNextPage}>Create</button>
        ...
```

Comment: Try checking out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425885/failed-to-execute-pushstate-on-history-error-when-using-window-history-pushs). Maybe also try not pushing the `addExpense()` function to state. I suspect this problem is an offshoot of a previous problem you were trying to solve recently, regarding passing props between routes. Please see my answer to that for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have seen this explanation but is there a solution for that? "use sessionStorage and/or localStorage". How do I implement that in this case? I'm quite a novice.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. That solution was left pre ReactJS / React Router. Not an appropriate implementation for your use case, but still useful to understand the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Firstly**, add some default value to your `addExpense` function:

```
  addExpense = (expense = DEFAULT) => {
    console.log('Hello From addExpense');
  }
```

**Then** Use `Link`:

```
<Link to={`/ideas/${this.addExpense}`}>Create Expense​</Link>
```

**OR** Try this (**Better Approach**):

```
  goToNextPage = (addExpense) => {
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/create',
      state: { addExpense: addExpense }
    });
  }
```

In next (`create`) component use the passed on values like this:

```
this.props.location.state.addExpense();
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I implement that goToNextPage? I create a button with `onClick={this.goToNextPage}`but getting an error `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

Comment: @karolis2017 use `fat arrow '=>'` or do `{this.goToNextPage.bind(this)}`. Also updated my answer.

Comment: now getting this `DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': [object Object] could not be cloned.`

Comment: can you replicate your issue [here](https://codepen.io/bradleyboy/pen/OPBpGw?editors)?

Comment: how do I do routes in codepen? how do I do `import from 'react-router-dom';`?

Comment: @karolis2017 U'll have to create a id for that I guess. But, can you replicate your issue anywhere online? Github? Or help me re-create your issue on my side?

Comment: this is the repo with current code: https://github.com/kstulgys/expenses-ci-app I hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it was caused by trying to route to a path with two `"/"` characters. I wrote this:

```
history.push(`${location.pathname}/somePath`);
```

... but if `location.pathname` is `"/"` that will try to go to `"//somePath"`, causing the error,

Answer (score 3):

You are using `BrowserRouter` which uses HTML5 history API(`window.history`),  unlike `Router` and `HashRouter`.

Mapping of BrowserRouter's `history.push` method to HTML5 history is below:

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/create',
  state: { addExpense: this.addExpense }
});
```

`pathname('/create')` > `window.history.push('create')`

`state({ addExpense: this.addExpense })` > `window.history.pushState({ addExpense: this.addExpense })`

The actual issue is with `window.history.pushState` as it stores the state as a `string` and has size limit of **640k characters**.

*Source*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using `BrowserRouter` and found out that I either needed to run a local server or switch to `HashRouter` since `BrowserRouter` does not work with a `file://` path due to security reasons.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6533#issuecomment-451969973

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same issue but when I changes all my backward slashes to forward slashes like below , error got resolved :-

```
 <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
               <li><NavLink to="/About">About</NavLink></li>
               <li><NavLink to="/Contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this, this is what worked for me :
Below is the page where you want to navigate:

```
export default function details(details): {....}
```

Below is the page from where you will navigate:

```
export default function starting() {
....
const history = useHistory()
history.push({
                pathname:"/details",
                details
            })
}
```

Notice how I didn't pass anything like `{state:details}`.
I'm just directly passing the array.