# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function () { [native code] } could not be cloned

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I am creating a small web app in reactjs template provided by visual studio 2017. I am stuck in a situation where i want a function to be passed as a state to a child component and then invoke that function through child component. I have a header component where i have a method called **setLogInTrue()** which i want to pass to my SignIn component. Below is my code:-

Header.tsx

```
class HeaderState {
isLoggedIn: boolean;
}

export class Header extends React.Component<HeaderProps, HeaderState> {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = ({ isLoggedIn: false });
    this.setLogInTrue= this.setLogInTrue.bind(this);
}

setLogInTrue() {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
}

public render(){
//Some elements
<NavLink className="link header_row_link" to={{ pathname: '/signIn', state: this.setLogInTrue }}> //<-- i thought this would work and give the function in the location of SignIn components state but it does not.
              Sign In
</NavLink>
  }
}
```

SignIn.tsx

```
export class SignIn extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}>  {

constructor() {
    super();
}

public render() {
    return <div className="signin_wrapper">
        <SignInContent />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

I want to access that function here and pass it to SignInContent component, and then invoke that function from there.

This code does not give me any compile time errors but whenever i click on the sign in link it gives me the following error

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function () { [native code] } could not be cloned.

i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46800237/why-failed-to-execute-pushstate-on-history-when-using-link-from-react-ro) solution but it does not work for me. It still gives me this error or gives state as undefined. I am very new to react and any help would be appreciated

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method): _"`pushState()` takes three parameters: a **state** object, a title, and a URL."_ -> _"The state object can be anything that can be **serialized**"_ -> _"Starting in Gecko 6.0 (Firefox 6.0 ...), the object is serialized using the **structured clone algorithm**."_ -> _"Things that **don't work** with structured clone: `Error` and **`Function` objects** cannot be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm; attempting to do so **will throw a DATA_CLONE_ERR exception**."_

Comment: If the function is not allowed then is there an alternate way to do so?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue when the React component state contained non serialized objects.

I just needed to stringify the whole React state object before pushing it to the browser's history state like this:

```
window.history.pushState(JSON.stringify(state), "", getSecuredURL(url));
```

Comment: Careful! Dates and perhaps other things don't do well with `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 6):

This error occurs, as @Andreas mentioned in a comment, when DOM elements or anything non-serializable is used in the state object which is being assigned to `window.history.state` via `history.replaceState` or `history.pushState`. For example try: `history.pushState({node: document.body}, 'title', '#/error')` or use `{node: History}` instead and it will produce a similar `DOMException` error. To fix it simply remove the problematic objects or in some way be more deliberate about what is being pushed into the state.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same issue with pushing a React component state that contained functions. I didn't want to call `JSON.strinfigy` though because it can contain dates and those don't stringify/parse well. Instead, I chose to do:

```
window.history.pushState(cleanStateForHistory(state), "", someURL);

/**
 * Remove the functions from the state. They can't been pushed into the history.
 */
export function cleanStateForHistory(state) {
  const stateWithNoFunctions = {};
  for (const key of Object.keys(state)) {
    if (typeof key !== "function") {
      stateWithNoFunctions[key] = state[key];
    }
  }
  return stateWithNoFunctions;
}
```