# How can I pass function using props in React Router Link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-props

I have to pass a function to another component using Link

```
    testFavorite=()=>{
        console.log("work")
    }

    <Link 
       to={{
       pathname: '/popular',
         state:{
            testFavorite: this.testFavorite
         }
       }}>
   Popular</Link>
```

This is how I call a function
`this.props.location.state.testFavorite();`

This is giving me this error

> DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': () => testFavorite() could not be cloned.

Comment: this code is not sufficient to clarify the issue. you need to provide more information, probably how you declare you `<Route>` for popular path, and it's component. you could consider adding a sandbox with the reproduced error.

Comment: You can find the code here
https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-resonance-qgi2m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/Header.js

Comment: Moreover, below is To the point question

function loadUser(){
      console.log("load")}

<Link to={{
  pathname: '/register',
  state: { user: this.loadUser }
}}/>


Upon executing this is giving me an error

Comment: it seems that state is serialized and  functions can't be serialized: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618225/uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute-pushstate-on-history-function)

Comment: Hey @UmarJaved , Did you get the solution of this. I am having the same problem. Please share the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `<Link />` component, I replace "state" property with "data" property. And it works now!

```
<Link 
    to={{
       pathname: '/popular',
       data:{
          testFavorite: this.testFavorite
       }
    }}
>
   Popular
</Link>
```

It will be accessable with this: `this.props.history.location.data`

Comment: Where did you find this solution? it's not even in Documentation, stackoverflow

Comment: Yes, the documentation is not complete. I only try to see what happen if I use "data" property because I've seen already in routes, we use "data" prop for passing data to a route.

Comment: @Ali Amini It's not seems to be working on page reload. Please help i am having the same problem. I need to pass the a function from link <Link to={{ state : { myFunction: the.myFunction } }}></Link> and want to call it into another page like this this.props.location.state.myFunction.