# Pass setState from useState() hook using <Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm having a problem with react-router when trying to pass `setState` from the `useState` hook using `<Link>`. What am I doing wrong?

I created simple project to show the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-surf-mj2vx?fontsize=14

Open console and click on the link to see the error.

```
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Link to={{ pathname: "/test", state: { state, setState } }}>test</Link>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm getting this error that does not help me resolve the issue:

> "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function () { [native code] } could not be cloned."

Comment: It's trying to clone what you're passing as `state` to the `Link`, but can't clone the `setState` function. Why *are* you passing that as state?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History' error when using window.history.pushState function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425885/failed-to-execute-pushstate-on-history-error-when-using-window-history-pushs)

Comment: what's a point to pass `setState` updater callback when navigating away from current component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the `setState` function in the `<Test />` component, pass it with the route instead:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0);

return (
    <div className="App">
        <Link to={{ pathname: '/test' }}>test</Link>
        <Switch>
            <Route
                path="/test"
                render={props => (
                    <Test {...props} state={state} setState={setState} />
                )}
            />
        </Switch>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This makes sense. Would you consider using context in this case?

My main motivation to pass it in <Link> was to update array kept in state of the parent component. As the link led to form that added a new element to the list.

It seems that in this case context would allow managing it in a better way.

Comment: Use context if it becomes unwieldy passing `state` and `setState` several levels deep, otherwise it's probably not the right solution. I would always start without using context, unless I know it's something that all components, everywhere, might need (logged in state and language settings for instance).